# C# cut out multiple Substrings starting with character

Tags: c#, string

I'm having the following string:

```
string nameString = "Sean Pen / 212321\n Chris Brown / 578,4\n Sandy Sanders / 879757"
```

I need to extract the names, so I have the following result:

```
Sean Pen 
Chris Brown 
Sandy Sanders
```

I've tried using substring methods like:

```
nameString = nameString(0,nameString.LastIndexOf("/")+1);
```

which removes the last number, but how can I extract every number after character '/' and still keep the names?

Comment: You are looking for `Regex`

Comment: Also last index doesn't make sense. To me it seems you just need the last index. Which is `Length-1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need regex, [`String.Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf(v=vs.110).aspx) and a little bit LINQ is enough:

```
string[] names = nameString.Split(new[] { "\r\n", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Select(s => s.Split('/')[0].Trim())
    .ToArray();
```

So first split by new-line characters to get three tokens, then split those by `/` to get only the first which contains the name. Finally remove leading or trailing white-spaces with [`String.Trim`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Regex if you wanted to, or you could do the following using regular .net string functions:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string nameString = "Sean Pen / 212321\n Chris Brown / 578,4\n Sandy Sanders / 879757";

    var names = ExtractNames(nameString);

    foreach (var name in names)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("-" + name + "-");
    }   
}

static List<string> ExtractNames(string input)
{
    return input.Split('\n').Select(RemoveNumbers).ToList();
}

static string RemoveNumbers(string input)
{
    return new string(input.Where(c => char.IsLetter(c) || char.IsSeparator(c)).ToArray()).Trim();
}
```

This will split the string into lines for each \n character and then it removes all characters that are not letters or separators. Finally it will trim the string to remove any white space

Comment: Regex is overkill for what he's asked about

Comment: Agreed. Regexes av overkill for most tasks :-)

Answer (score 0):

i assume your breaking this up because you want to use the data for something
Try using the Split function

if you split on "\n" and "/" you will have an array were the first element is the name and the second is a string of the number

```
foreach(var row in nameString.Split('\n','\r'))//covers line feed and carriage return
{
    data = row.Split('/'));
    name = data[0];
    number = data[1];
}
```

Comment: You might want to do `\n ` and ` / `. To remove the spaces.

Comment: actually i'd just trim them as i'm assuming that this string is manual input as no computerised process would require an output in that format

Comment: fair enough... do it ;)

Comment: I'm also assuming that we are doing his homework for him as this is exactly the sort of question they use to teach the fundamentals of programming

Answer (score 0):

A combination or regex and string functions should give you what you need.

```
var names = Regex.Replace("Sean Pen / 212321\n Chris Brown / 578,4\n Sandy Sanders / 879757", @"([^A-Za-z ])\w+", string.Empty).Split('/');

foreach (var name in names)
    Console.WriteLine(name.Trim());
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use the substring function

```
        string nameString = "Sean Pen / 212321\n Chris Brown / 578,4\n Sandy Sanders / 879757";

        string sean = nameString.Substring(0, 8);
        string chris = nameString.Substring(19, 11);
        string sandy = nameString.Substring(40, 14);

        Console.WriteLine(sean);
        Console.WriteLine(chris);
        Console.WriteLine(sandy);
```

Comment: this static aproach won't help, because the names change